# Linq and Lambda check condition on nested item

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have the following objects:

```
public class NestedObject
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public Datetime date {get; set;}
}

public class MainObject
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public List<NestedObject> object {get; set;}
}
```

I then have list of `MainObjects` `ObjList`

I now want to select the entries from `ObjList` where the newest date is newer than a given date.

If I had a list of `NestedObject` eg `NestObjList`, I would do the following

```
NestObjList.Where(x => x.date > givenDate);
```

I have considered:

```
ObjList.Where(x => x.object.date > givenDate);
```

but I do not think this will iterate through all entries in the nested list.

I know I can do this using a for Loop, but I am trying to do this with `Linq` and `Lambda`

Comment: You want a list of MainObject or NestObjects which match the criteria?

Comment: Why the downvotes??

Comment: @Alex I won't downvote this either, but deleting a question when people are trying to clarify and answer is rude and disrespectful of other people's time. You were trying to find entries whose maximum child objects occured before `givendate` ? Post a question asking about *that*. Not how you think the code should be written. Hint: Maximum values are returned with `Max()`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos My understanding is that a closed question should not be there?? And as there were no answers I thought the solution is to remove the question. I was not trying to be rude to you - I am grateful for your help. I am struggling to convey the question, and keep getting downvoted because of this. I feel I will not be able to get a solution to this question and I cannot see how else to ask it. Thank you for your assistance though-I am grateful to you. You have also helped me on other questions and I certainly dont want to ever be rude to you,so I apologise if I have offended you.

Comment: @Alex the solution is to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you wrote in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42924347/re-write-c-sharp-code-using-linq-and-lambda-can-it-be-done, something similar to this:

```
var changes = query
    .Where(x => (x.nestedObject.Max(y => (DateTime?)y.date) ?? DateTime.MinValue).CompareTo(date) < 0)
    .ToList();
```

You are looking for the `Max` date in the nested objects. You have to handle the case where there are no `nestedObject` (I use a default value of `DateTime.MinValue`).

Other variant, based on the `All()`

```
var changes2 = query
    .Where(x => x.nestedObject.All(y => y.date.CompareTo(date) < 0))
    .ToList();
```

The `MainObject`s where `All` the `nestedObject`s must have a `date` < the given `date`.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Enumerable.Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to check whether any nested object matches given condition

```
ObjList.Where(m => m.object.Any(n => n.date > givenDate))
```

Note:

- In C# we use *camelCase* for local variable names
- In C# we use *PascalCase* for properties, methods and type names
- Give a name in plural form for collections

**Update** (if you want to filter nested objects): LINQ is a querying tool. You cannot modify items and remove some nested objects from list. But you can create new main objects which will contain filtered data:

```
ObjList.Select(m => new MainObject {
    Name = m.Name,
    @object = m.object.Where(n => n.date > givenDate).ToList()
})
.Where(m => m.object.Any()) // remove if it's ok to have main objects without nested
```

**According to your deleted question**

```
 ObjList.Where(m => !m.object.Any(n => n.date > givenDate))
```

If you want not to include main object without nested into result, then you still have an option to filter them out by checking `m.object.Any()`

Comment: Wont 'Any' check if any of the items in this list meet this condition? I need it to only be the newest date. For example, if there are 2 dates in the nested list, one before and one after givenDAte, wont this always be true?

Comment: @Alex I'm confused a little - you are filtering `ObjList` with `Where`, but actually you want to filter nested objects and leave `ObjList` untouched?

Comment: No, for each ObjList I want to find the newest date for its entry in NestedList, and check that against givenDate. Then remove the entry from ObjList based on the result of this comparison

Comment: @Alex for your question this looks correct answer. If any of the MainObject has a nested object greater than current date then it will be selected. Do you want to get nested objects which match your criteria then you need to change your question.

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42924347/re-write-c-sharp-code-using-linq-and-lambda-can-it-be-done

Comment: @Alex your question is missing sample of input and expected/actual output you want to have. Don't try to describe your intentions by words - just give a sample

Comment: @Alex It would be better if you explain what you want to *include* rather than what you want to *remove*. In your other (currently deleted) question you use `newestDate < date` as criteria for adding (including) in the result which conflicts with your current question stating *where the newest date is **newer** than a given date*. If that was the intent, change the original answer criteria to `m => !m.object.Any(n => n.date >= givenDate))` and you are done. I'm pretty sure Sergey would have given you the correct answer if you formulated the question correctly.

Comment: @IvanStoev Any will not solve my issue please see my first comment to sergeys answer - Any will check this condition against all items in the list

Comment: @Alex Read my previous comment again. We don't know what your issue is. If it's what I think, then I provided you the correct condition. not any date >= given date means the newest date is < given date.

Comment: @Alex using `Any` **is** a solution here. If you have any date newer than given, then newest date will be newer than given

Comment: @IvanStoev but I am not looking for the condition where Any date is newer, I only want to compare the newest date

Comment: @Alex you do understand that searching newest date means *iterating all dates* and selecting max one? Same iteration will be done with checking `Any`. But `Any` will stop immediately instead of iterating all dates if there is at least one date which is newer than given date. Answer which you accepted is not optimized - it will *always* iterate all dates either for finding max date or checking condition for *all* dates.

Comment: @Alex All I was trying was to help. If you think a bit, you'll see that what I said is the equivalent of the answer you accepted. Anyway, hope you had your issue resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Any()` extension method like

```
ObjList.Where(x => x.object.Any(o => o.date > givenDate));
```

Also, consider not using *Reserve Word* for your class property name. Your `object` property should be named differently

```
public class MainObject
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public List<NestedObject> NestedObjects {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Wont 'Any' check if any of the items in this list meet this condition? I need it to only be the newest date. For example, if there are 2 dates in the nested list, one before and one after givenDAte, wont this always be true?